# Pulling images from private registry in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coreos

I have built a 4 node kubernetes cluster running multi-container pods all running on CoreOS. The images come from public and private repositories. Right now I have to log into each node and manually pull down the images each time I update them.  I would like be able to pull them automatically.

1. I have tried running docker login on each server and putting the .dockercfg file in /root and /core
2. I have also done the above with the .docker/config.json
3. I have added secret to the kube master and added imagePullSecrets:

   - name: docker.io to the Pod configuration file.

When I create the pod i get the error message Error:

```
image <user/image>:latest not found
```

If I log in and run docker pull  it will pull the image.  I have tried this using docker.io and quay.io.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kubernetes supports a special type of secret that you can create that will be used to fetch images for your pods. More details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod).

Comment: Did you need to create a service account?  I did those steps in the user-guide but it still doesn't pull the image.  Is a log to see what is going on?

Comment: You need to mount that secret into the pod in order for it to be used.

Comment: NOTE THAT: 1) the url must be https://  
2) the whole thing must be on 1 line
3) after base64 encoding it still should be on 1 line

Comment: answers should consist of more than just be a link and a one-sentence summary

Comment: The URL to the documentation has changed to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry

Comment: If you had put some more time explaining "why" the new "special" kind of secret would help resolving the issue, it would've helped me today to resolve what I'm facing. The link is wrong by today's date, and I have no idea what the "special kind of secret" means...

Answer (score 90):

To add to what @rob said, as of docker 1.7, the use of .dockercfg has been deprecated and they now use a ~/.docker/config.json file. There is support for this type of secret in kube 1.1, but you must create it using different keys/type configuration in the yaml:

First, base64 encode your `~/.docker/config.json`:

```
cat ~/.docker/config.json | base64 -w0
```

Note that the base64 encoding should appear on a single line so with -w0 we disable the wrapping.

Next, create a yaml file:
`my-secret.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: registrypullsecret
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: <base-64-encoded-json-here>
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

-

```
$ kubectl create -f my-secret.yaml && kubectl get secrets

NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA
default-token-olob7   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   2
registrypullsecret    kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1
```

Then, in your pod's yaml you need to reference `registrypullsecret` or create a replication controller:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-private-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: private
      image: yourusername/privateimage:version
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: registrypullsecret
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I also found that I needed to upgrade the version of k8s I was using.    Once I upgraded, everything worked as document.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. Also, as per the comment by @MrE on the previous answer, ensure that you have https:// on your private repository in your config.json prior to encoding it. Without it, I was failing to pull my containers.

Comment: The base64-encoded docker config needs to be all on one line. Probably best to use the base64 command with the "-w 0" flag.

Answer (score 35):

If you need to pull an image from a private Docker Hub repository, you can use the following.

**Create your secret key**

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

secret "myregistrykey" created.

Then add the newly created key to your Kubernetes service account.

**Retrieve the current service account**

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts default -o yaml > ./sa.yaml
```

Edit sa.yaml and add the ImagePullSecret after Secrets

```
imagePullSecrets:
- name: myregistrykey
```

**Update the service account**

```
kubectl replace serviceaccount default -f ./sa.yaml
```

Comment: This is most up to date answer, more details https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/service-accounts/#adding-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account

Comment: In case you want to pull from Azure Container Registry (ACR), you can use, for testing purposes, this method where you enable the admin user on ACR and create a secret containing the admin user info. For production purposes, you create a Service Principal (or service connection, which creates principals as I've understood it) then you put the *Principal's* info into the secret, like instructed here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks.md
Haven't yet tried Principals, but this admin user appr. worked for OpenShift too.

Comment: Most detailed answer and it works,just to add if you are using docker.io,please set -docker-server=docker.io

Answer (score 11):

I can confirm that imagePullSecrets **not working with deployment**, but you can

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
kubectl edit serviceaccounts default
```

Add

```
imagePullSecrets:
- name: myregistrykey
```

To the end after `Secrets`, save and exit.
And its works. Tested with Kubernetes 1.6.7

Answer (score 3):

For centos7, the docker config file is under /root/.dockercfg

1. echo $(cat /root/.dockercfg) | base64 -w 0
2. Copy and paste result to secret YAML based on the old format:

   ```
   apiVersion:  v1
   kind: Secret
   metadata:
     name: docker-secret
     type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg
   data:
     .dockercfg: <YOUR_BASE64_JSON_HERE>
   ```

And it worked for me, hope that could also help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create the secret with the same credentials that your docker configuration is with:

```
kubectl create secret generic myregistry --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=$HOME/.docker/config.json
```

This already encodes data in base64.

If you can download the images with docker, then kubernetes should be able to download them too. But it is required to add this to your kubernetes objects:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myregistry
      containers:
      # ...
```

Where `myregistry` is the name given in the previous command.

Answer (score 0):

go the easy way, do not forget to define `--type` and add it to proper namespace

```
kubectl create secret generic YOURS-SECRET-NAME \
--from-file=.dockerconfigjson=$HOME/.docker/config.json \
--type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```