# Image triggered K8 deployments in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, azure-pipelines, pipeline, acr

I have a K8 cluster set up on an on-prem server and I already have an azure build pipeline that pushes the image to an ACR. I was wondering if it was possible to trigger (or run a schedule for) Jenkins to pull the image from the ACR and do the new deployment like Flux V2 does? The reason is I need to be able to run post deployment tests (Automated UI tests for example) from the pipeline. As to my knowledge, this is not possible in Flux V2 (or in Fleet).

If there are any other suggestions I'm open to try them as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you wanna smtk like [Pull image Azure Container Registry - Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41207112/9929015)?

Comment: @Vit I am able to pull images from my ACR. I want to be able to automate this process. As soon as a new image is available I want my cluster to automatically deploy the new image