# How do you reference a private DockerHub image in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, dockerhub

I am using Kubernetes for the first time, and having a nasty time trying to reference a private DockerHub image.

In the yaml, this is what I have:

```
.... many other lines
-image: registry.hub.docker.com/MY_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/MY_IMAGE_NAME:latest
```

The error I'm getting says

```
Failed to pull image "registry.hub.docker.com/MY_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/MY_IMAGE_NAME:latest":
image pull failed for registry.hub.docker.com/MY_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/MY_IMAGE_NAME:latest, 
this may be because there are no credentials on this request. 
details: (Error: image MY_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/MY_IMAGE_NAME not found)
```

Now, I am a total know-nothing when it comes to Kubernetes configuration, but so far, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Possibly https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod, via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726923/pulling-images-from-private-registry-in-kubernetes

Comment: One mistake I made was not using `docker.io` as the domain for my image.

Comment: I should have said `docker.io/MY_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME/MY_IMAGE_NAME`

Comment: See the scripts in my answer at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037678/how-to-increase-dockerhub-rate-limits-within-kubeless
They will help you create the secret and patch the service accounts

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to create a secret key for your private repos an reference it in a deployment:

1. create the secret key

   ```
   kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
   ```
2. use it in a deployment

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: example
     namespace: default
   spec:
     replicas: 1
     strategy:
       rollingUpdate:
         maxSurge: 1
         maxUnavailable: 0
       type: RollingUpdate
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           run: example
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: example
           image: myregistryrepo/myimage:latest
           ports:
           - containerPort: 80
             name: http
           imagePullPolicy: Always
         imagePullSecrets:
           - name: myregistrykey
   ```

Comment: Yes, just retreive your credentials using `aws ecr get-login` and then create the secret like this: 

`kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-serverttps://xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --docker-username=AWS --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=none`

Comment: If deploying to AWS, set the cloud-provider to "aws" and it will automatically handle the credentials for you. Also, if not in AWS you could look at this repo (https://github.com/upmc-enterprises/registry-creds), which will handle the creds for you like @Camil suggested.

Comment: Supporting @SteveSloka comment. You can actually attach IAM role to aws ec2 instance and grant ecr permission (assuming you are running k8s in aws in same account). If you are running k8s in different aws account and your ecr repo located in different aws account, add readonly policies and grant permission for cross account on ecr repo.