# kubectl: I already have a .dockercfg file. How do I create a docker-registry secret with it?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

According to the [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-in-the-cluster-that-holds-your-authorization-token), I can create a `docker-registry` secret using the following command:

`kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>`

This generates a secret with a key of `.dockercfg`.

I already have a .dockercfg file generated by another tool, how can I use kubectl to create the `docker-registry` secret from my .dockercfg file?

Comment: Please check following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36709328/10347794) on similar question from 2016 on StackOverflow

Comment: did the solution provided in the link below work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Go the easy way, just create it from file.

Do not forget to define `--type` and add it to proper namespace

```
kubectl create secret generic YOURS-SECRET-NAME \
--from-file=.dockerconfigjson=$HOME/.docker/config.json \
--type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```