# How to use private registry provider, Service Account - from Kubernertes deployments

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, google-container-registry

**Update** I suspect this to be a google issue, I have created a new more clean question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416886/authentication-methods-using-a-json-key-file-unauthorized-gcr-login-failed).

**Update**: yes this is different than the suggested "This question may already have an answer here:", as this is about a "Service Account" - not a "User accounts".

Do you now how to use a private registry like Google Container Registry from DigitalOcean or any other Kubernetes not running on the same provider?

I tried following [this](http://docs.heptio.com/content/private-registries/pr-gcr.html), but unfortunately it did not work for me.

**Update**: I suspect it to be a Google SA issue, I will go and try using Docker Hub and get back if that succeeds. I am still curious to see the solution for this, so please let me know - thanks!
**Update**: Also tried [this](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-kubernetes/0.3.0/private-registry.html)
**Update**: tried to activate [Google](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) Service Account
**Update**: tried to [download](https://container-solutions.com/using-google-container-registry-with-kubernetes/) Google Service Account key
**Update**: in the linked description is says:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry $SECRETNAME \
  --docker-server=https://gcr.io \
  --docker-username=_json_key \
  --docker-email=user@example.com \
  --docker-password="$(cat k8s-gcr-auth-ro.json)"
```

Is the `--docker-password="$(cat k8s-gcr-auth-ro.json)"` really the password?

If I do `cat k8s-gcr-auth-ro.json` the format is:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "<xxx>",
  "private_key_id": "<xxx>",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\<xxx>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "k8s-gcr-auth-ro@<xxx>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<xxx>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/k8s-gcr-auth-ro%<xxx>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

**kubectl get pods**
I get: .`..is waiting to start: image can't be pulled`

from a deployment with:

```
image: gcr.io/<project name>/<image name>:v1
```

deployment.yaml

```
# K8s - Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <image-name>-deployment-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <image-name>-deployment
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: <image-name>
        image: gcr.io/<project-name>/<image-name>:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <name-of-secret>
```

I can see from the following that it logs: `repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

kubectl describe pod :

```
k describe pod <image-name>-deployment-v1-844568c768-5b2rt

Name:               <image-name>-deployment-v1-844568c768-5b2rt
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               my-cluster-digitalocean-1-7781/10.135.153.236
Start Time:         Mon, 25 Mar 2019 15:51:37 +0100
Labels:             app=<image-name>-deployment
                    pod-template-hash=844568c768
                    version=v1
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 <ip address>
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/<image-name>-deployment-v1-844568c768
Containers:
  chat-server:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          gcr.io/<project-name/<image-name>:v1
    Image ID:       
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-dh8dh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-dh8dh:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-dh8dh
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From                                        Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----                                        -------
  Normal   Scheduled       50s                default-scheduler                           Successfully assigned default/<image-name>-deployment-v1-844568c768-5b2rt to my-cluster-digitalocean-1-7781
  Normal   Pulling         37s (x2 over 48s)  kubelet, my-cluster-digitalocean-1-7781  pulling image "gcr.io/<project-name><image-name>:v1"
  Warning  Failed          37s (x2 over 48s)  kubelet, my-cluster-digitalocean-1-7781  Failed to pull image "gcr.io/<project-name>/<image-name>:v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gcr.io/<project-name>/<image-name>, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
  Warning  Failed          37s (x2 over 48s)  kubelet, my-cluster-digitalocean-1-7781  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   SandboxChanged  31s (x7 over 47s)  kubelet, my-cluster-digitalocean-1-7781  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   BackOff         29s (x6 over 45s)  kubelet, my-cluster-digitalocean-1-7781  Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/<project-name>/<image-name>:v1"
  Warning  Failed          29s (x6 over 45s)  kubelet, my-cluster-digitalocean-1-7781  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Just a note: docker pull on local machine pulls the image alright

Comment: What is the error presented? I saw the doc and seems complete.

Comment: Thanks, I updated with error: "image can't be pulled" & image name

Comment: have you put image pull secrets on deploy? Have you added regcred on secrets? Try to delete your pods. Maybe the were launched before the secret creation.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately I get the same. Just updated with kubectl describe pod

Comment: try this tutorial: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/ . It is simpler, does not have a serviceAccount linked to the secret.

Comment: Seems correct your configuration.

Comment: How did you create the image pull secret?

Comment: Like in the link: http://docs.heptio.com/content/private-registries/pr-gcr.html

Comment: Looks like it's not identifying your imagePullSecret, check out https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-by-providing-credentials-on-the-command-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulling images from private registry in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726923/pulling-images-from-private-registry-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Update: s the --docker-password="$(cat k8s-gcr-auth-ro.json)" really the password?

Comment: You say `docker pull on local machine pulls the image alright` - how did you log in on your local machine? Do you pull with the full image name including gcr.io etc?  Are you using the same service account credentials that you're putting into the Kubernetes secret (the `$(cat k8s-gcr-auth-ro.json) stuff) ?

Comment: Yes I use the full grc.io/<proj>/container:tag and to authenticate I used: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Comment: Did you do the `patch` step for the k8s service account that's mentioned in the docs and do you use the `default` service account for your deployment as that's the one that's patched as per the guide you linked to?

Comment: Thanks, yes I did. i kind of moved to try to see if I can get my own registry running on DigitalOcean and have it TLS secure. Just if you know anything regarding this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379600/letsencrypt-email-account-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes